# UnicodeDecodeError when reading JSON file with emojis

Tags: python, json

I want to read JSON file with Python. The problem is that JSON file has emojis as some values.
JSON file looks like this:

`{"data": [{"id": "18012853735218880", "from": {"username": "g7741952"}, "text": "T\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d", "created_time": "15562685603"}], "meta": {"code": 200}}`

Text value is emoji. I have tried this:

```
data = json.load(open('comments.json'))
print(data)
```

And I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 84-84: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

Then I have tried this:

```
data = json.load(open('comments.json', encoding='utf16'))
print(data)
```

And I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x7d in position 176: truncated data
```

I do not know what to try next, I have searched all overt the site

Comment: Please provide a sample content of the comments.json

Comment: data = json.load(open('comments.json', encoding='utf_16_le')) try this.

Comment: it gives me this error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x7d in position 176: truncated data
`

Comment: @Christopher check out my question. I have updated it. I have added the JSON file, the look of json file

Comment: You may also have to include which environment are you running your script. I was able to run the script in a linux machine and it was printed as plain text.